# Angular 4 to 5 update WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I have updated Angular 4 to 5 according to this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3), after this my build failed on webpack with two warnings:

```
  WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
      6553:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
       @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
       @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
       @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts

  WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
  6573:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
   @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
   @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
   @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

I went through this [topic](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898), but nothing helps (maybe I miss something). This is how my webpack.config.vendor.js plugins look:

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', Popper: 'popper.js' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
    ]
```

I originally use Angular template with .NET Core API from Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` to see if that cleared up the warnings? That has worked for me in the past when moving from ng4 to ng5 with the template you are using.

Comment: Your are right! Can you make your comment as answer? So I can accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Glad this helped.

Comment: Yea, that's a tricky one. This typically happens on first build, but if the vendor file already exists VS2017 tempalte wont recreate it (check your *.csproj file, the build command is in there). also deleting the dist folders (both in wwwroot and in projects folder helps too, as it will trigger it to be built again when you build your asp.net core project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the newer Angular template that now comes with VS 2017, and you upgrade Angular version 4 to 5.x.x, you need to run the following command in order to avoid some warnings you get at compile time.

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

Running this from the command prompt while at the root of the project removes the warnings that you see in the OP above.

What this does is rebuild the *vendor.js* file in the *wwwroot/dist* folder to update it based on the Angular (and other) npm packages you have installed.

Comment: Deleting dist folder helps too, as the existence of the dist folder (in project not inside wwwroot) is the condition within csproj file

Comment: I see that now. The *vendor.js* file in the *ClientApp/dist* folder got updated, too. Thanks for the information.

Comment: vendor.js in Client/App/dist is created by the above commend and is used for the client sided bundling (`webpack.config.js`)

Answer (score 2):

There can be an issue with the expression you are passing in the ContextReplacementPlugin of webpack file.

I changed it

**from**

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('src'), 
            {}
        )
```

**to**

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(\@angular|esm5)/,
            helpers.root('src'),
            {}
        )
```

This worked for me. Hope it helped:)