# Upgraded app works but looks wrong - Angular 4 to 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular5

I have spent the last 24 hours trying to upgrade an Angular 4 app created from ASP.NET Core template into an Angular 5 app with no success. I then tried to upgrade a brand new app (no modifications) to Angular 5 and even though the app seems to work - it is visually all wrong (see image below).

I have done nothing more than a few simple steps that are mentioned everywhere as the "proper way" to upgrade Angular 4 app. I have used just [one of the tutorials](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/) but they are more or less all the same (also [tried this](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)).

My environment: Node.js: 8.9.4, @angular/cli: 1.6.8

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch Visual Studio 2017
2. Create new ASP.NET Core Web Application with Angular template
3. Build and run. Works normally.
4. Follow steps from Angular 5 upgrade tutorial.
5. Build and run. Works normally but looks wrong.

[image]

### UPDATE

If I simply copy *vendors.css* created by an Angular 4 project to the *wwwroot\dist* of an Angular 5 project, the appearance seems back to normal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with c#, please don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: Just looks like missing CSS to me, do you have any browser console errors? 404s perhaps?

Comment: You need to compare the "working" site with the "non working" site and figure out what is responsible for the styling (probably a css file but maybe multiple files). Once you know what file is responsible for the (missing) styling then figure out why it is not being loaded in the upgraded site (maybe you need a reference in your angular cli config?). If you are still stuck then update your question with the relevant details you got from doing the above.

Comment: @DavidG, no errors whatsoever. @ Igor, I do not have a "working" site to compare to. This is probably something in the webpack domain but could also be an Angular issue. I am too weak in this area to be able to hunt it down. I did waste 24 hours already trying to fix this any way I could. I did notice that Angular 4 "vendor.css" is double the size of Angular 5 "vendor.css". So something is being left out. Not sure where or why. I was hoping someone with VS could figure this out in minutes...

Comment: Have you considered using https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ 
from angular devs?

Comment: @VagrantAI. Yes, I did so. Forgot to mention it. The instructions are pretty much the same. Also, those are general instructions. I believe the problem has something to do with .NET Core / webpack.

Comment: Did you use some custom webpack configuration on Angular 4 or made a build via webpack?

Comment: @VagrantAI. I used the steps 1-5 as described in the question. Nothing more.

Comment: Please comment more specifically on how you build your app before and after, which command was executed and so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165064/discussion-between-vagrantai-and-wpfwannabe).

Comment: Try the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724378/455493) and see my comment on the accepted answer

Comment: @Tseng, unfortunately that doesn't work. I have encountered your answer and tried it. I also tried deleting everything in *dist*. Files get rebuilt but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of research i found a solution for this problem, the issue is that during the update you have updated bootstrap to v. 4.0.0 to fix it i have downgraded bootstrap to v. 3.3.7 as follow:

1. Open visual studio.
2. Open packages.json.
3. Find bootstrap entry and change the version to 3.3.7.
4. Close visual studio.
5. Open power shell in the root folder of the application.
6. Run npm install
7. Run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
8. Open visual studio and run your project.

Comment: I believe I found it to be the same resolution on an unrelated project. I did not have time to verify that it was the case so thanks for posting the answer. I hope it helps others. For people commonly using VS and SPA templates this should be a huge time saver.